# Value is not updating after deleting an input value

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I just implemented a swipe to delete function in my code, and it works perfectly. However, it does not update my current calculation which is based on the the values in the `tableview`. The `tableview` reloads but, the number in the label does not recalculate.

Once I move to a different tab and come back the label is reloaded to the right amount, but that is due to a reloadsections in segmented controller. How can I reload the data in the text in my label?

Code Snippet is given below:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FoodEntry *foodEntry = [[StorageController sharedInstance] entriesForEssential:self.displayEssential][indexPath.row];
    [[StorageController sharedInstance] removeFoodEntry:foodEntry forEssential:self.displayEssential];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.currentPlaceHolder.text ????
        }
}
```

Comment: tableView reloadData updates only the view. To adjust any values you have to update the model, the items in the table view data source

Comment: @vadian Thanks. Still trying to figure out how to do that. I appreciate the help!